# How I can get value from WebView and push to the notification

Tags: java, android, cookies

I just started to develop for Android recently and don't know much about Java

My problem is I want show my website on `webView`, but how I can get a value from my URL and pass it to a notification?
With cookie?
With Session?
With JSON Url?

For example you will go to www.test.com by your PC and you will see have 5 notification ( Actually this value is saved into a cookie ) , Is there any way that I can get cookie of my website from  `webView` of application and  it into a notification of android app ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push that specific cookie from your computer to the Android Phone, or at least it would be really inconvenient.

But since you have to build the cookie from data, that data should be available for use buy GCM https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Another alternative is to create a scheduled task that visits the website, gets the cookie and displays a notification if necessary.

I must say the question is rather vague, if you could be more specific it would probably help solve your problem!

Comment: OK Let me ask another way ! I have a website and an android application that show my website in WebView , How I can get a value from URL of my website and push it as notification ?